# How to display a row where the first column falls under the maximum condition, and the second under the minimum condition?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm doing a study assignment. I have a small data set:

```
Last_name <- c("Lyons","Wilkinson","Chambers","Thornton","Holland")
Salary_dollars <- c(2285, 2351, 3654, 2121, 3098)
Work_experience_months <- c(24, 17, 72, 12, 44)

df <- data.frame(Last_name, Salary_dollars, Work_experience_months)
print(df)
   Last_name    Salary_dollars    Work_experience_months
1      Lyons              2285                         24
2   Wilkinson             2351                         17
3    Chambers             3654                         72
4    Thornton             2121                         12
5     Holland             3098                         44
```

I can display information separately, that is, about the worker with the highest salary and the worker with the least experience.

```
Factory_workers[which.max(Factory_workers$Salary_dollars),]
Factory_workers[which.min(Factory_workers$Work_experience_months),]
```

How can I arrange this request so that these two conditions are in one request? I need to display information about the worker with the highest salary and the least experience.

Update, full text of the assignment:

```
Information about five workers of the shop is given. 
The columns have names: last name, salary, work experience. 
Display data about the worker with the 
highest salary and the least length of service.
```

it seems to me that a relative connection of these two indicators is needed here and the output should be one line.

Comment: It would make life easier if your dataframe name was short, e.g. `fw`

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Last_name <- c("Lyons","Wilkinson","Chambers","Thornton","Holland")
Salary_dollars <- c(2285, 2351, 3654, 2121, 3098)
Work_experience_months <- c(24, 17, 72, 12, 44)

dt <- data.table(Last_name, Salary_dollars, Work_experience_months)


dt[, .SD[Salary_dollars == max(Salary_dollars) | 
         Work_experience_months == min(Work_experience_months)],
     ]

   Last_name Salary_dollars Work_experience_months
1:  Chambers           3654                     72
2:  Thornton           2121                     12
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a dplyr option.

Assuming the dataframe = df as per response from *jadel*

```
bind_rows(dt %>% slice_max(Salary_dollars,n=1,with_ties=FALSE), #slice_max() will filter the first row with highest "Salary_dollars"
          dt %>% slice_min(Work_experience_months,n=1,with_ties=FALSE)) # slice_min() is opposite of above based on "Work_experience_months"
```

**Output**

```
  Last_name Salary_dollars Work_experience_months
1  Chambers           3654                     72
2  Thornton           2121                     12
```